# How to customize the appearance of a qr code

Tags: java, android, ios, nativescript

I've built a QR Code creator, but now I need to know how to customize the appearance of the codes.

The first image is an example of how they are currently outputted. The second is what I'd like to achieve.

The two codes are exactly the same. It's just their appearance that's different.

Just don't no where to begin. Any direction would be helpful.

---

### The Generator Code

For now I've only written for iOS. But will be for android too, which is why I included the android tag.

**Note** I'm working with *NativeScript* so this might look a bit odd to *iOS* developers, but this is how we access native *iOS* methods etc...

```
const message = NSString.stringWithString("My Message");
const data = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
const data_filter = CIFilter.filterWithNameWithInputParameters(
    "CIQRCodeGenerator",
    { inputMessage: data, inputCorrectionLevel: "M" }
);
const code = data_filter.outputImage;
const size = CGRectIntegral(code.extent);
const output_size = CGSizeMake(150, 150);
const matrix = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(
    output_size.width / CGRectGetWidth(size),
    output_size.height / CGRectGetHeight(size)
);
const transformed = code.imageByApplyingTransform(matrix);
const image = UIImage.imageWithCIImage(transformed);
```

---

### This is what I get

[image: A QR Code with the default square dot modules.]

---

### This is what I want

[image: A QR Code with smaller circle dot modules]

---

Comment: May be this lib help you check this url
https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/4340

Comment: Use this demo project : https://github.com/scola/Qart

Comment: What are you using to create the QR codes? Share some code related to drawing the code.

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke Added code currently in use.

Comment: Thanks @RashpalSingh and Abhinav Cupta, I'll definitely look into that one when I get going on Android.